# Fixed Server roles

Tags: sql-server, security, windows

Can users who are members of SQL2008's server DBCreator role, access databases created/restored by another user with the same permissions, without having to grant any additional permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user becomes the owner of any database they create (meaning they can do pretty much anything to it including rename it or drop it), but they are unable to access databases created by other db_creator members.

More info [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/sqlserversecurityfixedroles/1163/)

Comment: That's funny, because I just created a new, regular user on my server, and gave them the "dbcreator" role.  They were able to DELETE databases they didn't own, even though they couldn't otherwise access them.  "dbcreator" at the server-role level means they can CREATE and DELETE any database.

Comment: See note at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx   "Members of the dbcreator fixed server role can create, alter, drop, and restore ANY database."

Comment: That's true, but they can't access the data within them or modify security on them unless they're the owner.